# Adding a point to variable every second doesn't work (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static

```
public static int pscore = 0;
void Start()
{
     InvokeRepeating("AddToMoney",1, 1);  
}
void AddToMoney ()
{
     pscore++;
}
```

I have this code to add a point to integer pscore every second. But right now it adds 2 points instead of one. Is it because it's static? And if so, how can I fix it? Or how can I transfer one variable from script to another script without using static?

Note: I couldn't get answer in the unity3d forums, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: That's weird, the could should, as it stands, only increment the score by 1 every second. What are other pieces of code accessing the `pscore` variable? Sounds like a side-effect of something else.

Comment: Have you considered not adding on a timed event, but calculating on demand how much money the player has based on the time?

Comment: **DO NOT USE STATIC** ever in Unity.  It's remarkable you haven't seen this warning somewhere.

Comment: note that InvokeRepeating takes **floats** as arguments.  `InvokeRepeating("Add", 1f, 1f)`  Do not forget the "f"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add a point to integer pscore every second

```
bool keepIncrementing = false;
public static int pscore = 0;
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(IncementEachSecond());
}

IEnumerator IncementEachSecond()
{
    keepIncrementing = true;
    while (keepIncrementing)
    {
        pscore++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}

void stopIncrementing()
{
    keepIncrementing = false;
}
```

> how can I transfer one variable from script to another script without
>   using static

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour{

    public int pscore = 0;

    void Start()
    {

    }
}
```

Access variable `pscore` in `ScriptA` from `ScriptB`.

```
public class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour{

    ScriptA scriptInstance = null;  

    void Start()
    {
      GameObject tempObj = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectScriptAIsAttachedTo");
      scriptInstance = tempObj.GetComponent<ScriptA>();
      scriptInstance.pscore = 5;
    }
}
```